# CPU and Memory Cap for an AppDomain

Tags: memory, cpu, appdomain

I want to host an exe in an appdomain and assign a CPU and Memory cap to it so that it does not use more than the assigned processing power. Is this possible to do and how?

Answer (score 3):

You can't cap the maximum memory directly, as far as I know.

However, from .NET 4 on, the memory currently allocated by an `AppDomain` is available in the [`AppDomain.MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.monitoringtotalallocatedmemorysize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property if [`AppDomain.MonitoringIsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.monitoringisenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set to `true`. You can spin up a watchdog thread to monitor allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a solution for this requirement in .NET 4.0

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hasansheik/diagnostic-and-performance-monitoring-in-dotnet-4-0/

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer in case the link dies.

Comment: This link is to read-only properties. The question was on how to SET these values.

Answer (score 0):

Even the Windows performance monitors don't allow you to view CPU usage by AppDomain - since AppDomains are logical constructs of the CLR and are not known by the OS  the only CPU usage tracking is at process level - I would be shocked if there is a way to limit something that you can't even monitor.

What exactly is your reason for wanting to do this? Why wouldn't you want your application to use all resources available to it? If it is simply a case of making sure there is enough overhead for other processes to run can't you just set the priority of the threads very low and let the Windows scheduler figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do something like this is using HyperV (or similar products) and partitioning your applications into different virtual machines. But that's not exactly a cheap or simple solution.