# c# set upper bound for max memory my application can use

Tags: c#, memory-management, appdomain

I am writing an application which searches for solutions to simple problems and I am testing various algorithms.  I would like the system to throw an out of memory exception before paging to disk, and to run my software at various levels of memory availability.  Is this possible?

I figured the AppDomain was the best place to look, but I was only able to find total memory allocated since app domain was created.  I did find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717370/cpu-and-memory-cap-for-an-appdomain), but I do not care about CPU at all and just want to focus on disallowing paging for my app.

Comment: maybe maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852062/limiting-process-memory-with-maxworkingset) be useful, take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You can limit various metrics such as memory and CPU usage per process. This can be done using Windows Job Objects. This is a kernel facility. You'll have to use unsafe code to access it.